# Writing a django query the other way

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

I have this simple forum-app:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Topic(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    body = models.TextField()
```

I want to count all postings in a `Board`. One way is to call:

```
class Board(...):
    ...
    def post_count(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).count()
```

But is there a way not starting from the Post.objects but from the Board-model? Like `Board.objects...`? So I don't need any further method in my board class and use something builtin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use related managers from each of the objects that have a foreign key pointing at them to make queries from the other side of those foreign key relationships. By default, these so-called reverse related managers are named {model-with-foreign-key}_set, and exist on any object of a model pointed at by another model's foreign key relationship.

[Here's what the Django documentation has to say about traversing relationships in reverse order.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Here's an example of working backwards through the relationships using your suggested problem:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    ...
    def post_count(self):
        count = 0
        for topic in self.topic_set:
            count += topic.post_set.count()
        return count
```

Your initial method seems more readable to me, though.

Comment: No kidding! Your original solution makes a single query into the database, but this one requires a loop. This is a case where reverse relations are not the most effective method to accomplish your goal.